# Auto Suggest module

Tags: php, database, autosuggest

I am working on a search bar for my website which has an auto-suggest feature. I implemented this using php, ajax, jquery, and mysql.

Now I want that the result should be displayed as a link, so if user clicks on a result it will redirect the user to that page.

I also want the search result in this format:

[image]

My code is:

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Autocomplete textbox using jQuery, PHP and MySQL by CodexWorld</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'search.php'
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
  <input id="skills" autofocus="">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'search_demo';
//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
//get matched data from skills table
$query = $db->query("SELECT skill,category FROM skills WHERE skill LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY skill ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['skill'];
}
//return json data
$var = json_encode($data);
echo $var;
?>
```

My database has three fields `id`, `skill`, and `category`.

The current result is:

[image]

Comment: You are wide open to SQL-injection. You should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. First one is to [extend the jqueryUI autocomplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#extension-points), with the [widgets factory](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/). Second one is to create your own autocomplete script, which is in fact simple and is good for learning.